# How to interrupt an unresponsive RestTemplate call earlier than the normal response time

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, resttemplate

Below is our call to a third party service:

```
try {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = new RestTemplate().exchange(
                        requestUrl,
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        new HttpEntity<String>(null, new HttpHeaders()),
                        String.class);
    // Log the response received (and request sent) 
    log.info(String.format("3rd party response: %s for request: %s" + response, requestUrl));
} catch (CustomTimeoutException e) {
    log.error(String.format("Call to 3rd party with %s failed with: %s", requestUrl, e));
}
```

If the requested service is not available, it takes 30 seconds to timeout.  We have no control over their timeout time, so we'd like to throw, catch and handle a custom exception if we don't hear back in 3 seconds.

Not very experienced with threading so a concrete example of how this specific code would fit into the solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> We have no control over their timeout time

Do not care about the server timeouts. As an HTTP client, you can define your own timeouts, on two distinct levels:

- a **connection** timeout : how long max to reach the target server
- a **read** timeout : allowing you to give up after a certain amount of time (and potentially earlier than the server will abort) in case the HTTP response does not come

See Spring doc on how to configure these two timeouts.